# zsh: create file and open in editor

Tags: terminal, sublimetext3, zsh

Does anyone know of any neat shortcuts to create a file and open it in an editor (in my case Sublime) at the same time?

Something like `touch some/nice/file.txt | st ...` or `touch some/nice/file.txt && ...something`

(`st` being my sublime shortcut, which can take an argument)

`touch some/nice/file.txt && st some/nice/file.txt` works of course, but involves repeating the file name, and it would be nice to do it without!

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you just do `st somefile.txt`, Sublime will still create a tab for the file even though the file doesn't exist; is there a reason to touch the file first?

Comment: @OdatNurd You make a very good point! I sort of already knew that but for some reason I hadn't thought about things in that way!

Answer (score 1):

You can put an alias in your .zshrc to shorten it to whatever you want. Just add a line like

```
alias to='to(){ touch $1; st $1 }; to '
```

to your zshrc.

Now if you type 'to some/nice/file.txt' in your shell it should make the file and open it. You will need to reload the terminal once or use 'source .zshrc' before it can work.